# How to save leap date '02/29/2006' to sql server database?

Tags: c#, sql

I can' t save this leap date '02/29/2006' to sql server database. I'm using C#. Is there any particular code for this? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well, 02/29/2006 is not a leap date, that is why. 2000, 2004 and 2008 is ,check the dates.

Comment: Got a calendar? Check 2006. Was it leap?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's because it's not a leap year? :)

**2006 is not a leap year**. Leap years occur usually every four years (those years whose number is **divisible by four**) except for century years (divisible by 100) whose number is not divisible by 400. 2006 is not divisible by 4, so it fails the first condition.

Answer (score 1):

You Cant save it - Because it wasnt a leap year:

[image]

Comment: I apologize for my wrong question. Thanks for your time.